# Why ethereum has multiple cli?

Tags: go-ethereum, cli

Bitcoin has just a single cli while ethereum has multiple cli. what is the need of multiple CLI ?

Comment: the CLI is part of the client, so if there are multiple clients, there will be multiple CLIs

Comment: What do you mean by multiple cli? There's multiple clients. Do you ask why cli or each client are different or why there is multiple client like geth, besu, openethereum, nethermind,... ?